# Why there is ticking noise and turn indicator lights blinking in car while driving even if I'm not touching the lever?

Tags: repair, electronics, turn-signal, central-locking, flasher

I own a Tata motors Indica DLS V2. I've noticed that there is ticking noise (similar to the one produced during turn signal) and turn indicator lights blink while driving, even if I'm not even touching the lever. This happens especially when I'm driving on bad roads with large potholes. As soon as the car encounters a pothole there is this ticking noise and turn indicator lights goes blinking and they won't stop for some good amount of time.
I once showed my car to a mechanic. All he did was soldering in the circuit board of the central parking system (I suppose). Mechanic was such a jerk, he didn't explained me fully what he repaired in car. 
Please suggest me what could be the necessary change or repair needed. This is my first owned car and I'm not so good with all the electronic assembly of car.

Comment: If you aren't good with cars and electronics then I'd recommend you don't try and fix this yourself, it would be easy to make the problem worse if you do the wrong thing. There's an electrical loose connection in wiring, a problem with a control module or the signal control mechanism (the physical switch that connect to the signal arm. I know nothing about Tata cars so can't give specific advice.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: CHECK THE EMERGENCY FLASHERS SWITCH TO MAKE SURE IT'S NOT PARTIALLY STUCK.